# Htaccess rewrite multiple urls to same file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite these URLs to the same file and just one is working fine.

`RewriteRule ^api/cart/?(.*) index.php?$1&route=extension/feed/rest_api/cart [L,QSA]`
ps: `cart` is a method inside rest_api file **this is working fine**

`RewriteRule ^api/v2/cart/?(.*)$ index.php?$1&route=extension/feed/rest_api/cartv2 [L,QSA]`

ps: `cartv2` is another method at same file `rest_api`

ps2: If I add `v2` on URL it stop works.

ps3: If I change this rewrite to `RewriteRule ^api/cartv2/?(.*)$ index.php?$1&route=extension/feed/rest_api/cartv2 [L,QSA]`

or anything else like `RewriteRule ^api/foo/?(.*)$ index.php?$1&route=extension/feed/rest_api/cartv2 [L,QSA]`

or `RewriteRule ^api/bar/?(.*)$ index.php?$1&route=extension/feed/rest_api/cartv2 [L,QSA]`

Works fine.

Could someone help me?

**Edit 1:** url NOT working: https://www.example.com/api/v2/cart

**Full htaccess file:** https://pastebin.com/vVVWbJJ0

Comment: First you need to log your rewrites so you can see what the log shows.  Can you update your post and give an example of an URL that's NOT working with the given rewrite rather than just the rewrite regex?  Also, can you post the full htaccess file?  Rewrites will mess with each other so if one of your rewrites gets caught up, it won't process the next one which is why the log is important.

Comment: @DataHerder Added edits.

Comment: It works fine because it just skips the rewrites and does it's usual thing.  BTW your htaccess file is private so I can't view it.

Comment: @DataHerder changed paste exposure.

Comment: At this point you'll need to turn on logging because it's hard to judge what it's doing.  There's a bit of rewrites in there.  Do you have logging turned on?